# Image retrieve gives error Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get image at pageload from database to a img control but i receive this error.
"Index was outside the bounds of the array." at line "long retrievedBytes = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, buffer, 0, ChunkSize);"

```
<img runat="server" id="image" alt="" height="100" width="100"/>

protected void LoadImages()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sps_getimage", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad_id", 10010);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        reader.Read();
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
        long startIndex = 0;
        const int ChunkSize = 256;
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
            long retrievedBytes = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, buffer, 0, ChunkSize);
            memory.Write(buffer, 0, (int)retrievedBytes);
            startIndex += retrievedBytes;
            if (retrievedBytes != ChunkSize)
                break;
        }

        byte[] data = memory.ToArray();
        memory.Dispose();
        image.Src = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: If this is `ASP.Net` why are you using an `<img />` tag and not a `<asp:Image />` one? Your code doesn't even look like it will compile, what is with the random `<strong>` tag in the while loop? Please include a short complete example of how to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `startIndex` parameter in the `GetBytes` method is referring to the starting index in the target array, not the source. Just use `0` there.

Oh, and use `using` instead of manually calling `Dispose`:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  // Work as usual
}

// Dispose is called automatically, even if there's an unhandled exception
```